# Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex, triggers, typechecking, enforcement

Suppose I have an attribute called phone number and I would like to enforce certain validity on the entries to this field. Can I use regular expression for this purpose, since Regular Expression is very flexible at defining constraints.

Comment: Short answer: Yes you can. Could you add more context ? Would you like to filter it at input ? If so why don't you filter when the user signs-up for example ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV No, not at input. I want to enforce this in the database. I understand it can be done by in the application layer, I was wondering if the same was possible in the database layer when creating the tables.

Comment: When creating a table, you have to specify a column type, there is no "phone number" type. You may want to look at [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can. MySQL supports regex (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) and for data validation you should use a trigger since MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraint (you can always move to PostgreSQL as an alternative:). NB! Be aware that even though MySQL does have CHECK constraint construct, unfortunately MySQL (so far 5.6) does not validate data against check constraints. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html: "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."

You can add a check constraint for a column **phone**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data (
  phone varchar(100)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_phone_check BEFORE INSERT ON data
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.phone REGEXP '^(\\+?[0-9]{1,4}-)?[0-9]{3,10}$' ) = 0 THEN 
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wroooong!!!';
END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;


INSERT INTO data VALUES ('+64-221221442'); -- should be OK
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('+64-22122 WRONG 1442'); -- will fail with the error: #1644 - Wroooong!!!
```

However you should not rely merely on MySQL (data layer in your case) for data validation. The data should be validated on all levels of your app.

Comment: Thanks. This is something I was looking for. I understand that all validation should be done at all layers, but I needed to know how it's done for data layer.

Comment: This is the create table query:
create table fk
(
    empid int not null unique, 
    age int check(age between 18 and 60), 
    email varchar(20) default 'N/A', 
    secondary_email varchar(20) check(secondary_email RLIKE'^[a-zA-Z]@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-z,A-Z]{2,4}'),
    deptid int check(deptid in(10,20,30))
)
;
\n
This INSERT query will work:\n
insert into fk values(1,19,'a@a.com','a@b.com', 30);\n
This INSERT query will not work:\n
insert into fk values(2,19,'a@a.com','a@bc.com', 30);

Comment: So we can set regular expression in the Check Constraint of create table.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL 8.0.16 (2019-04-25) and MariaDB 10.2.1 (2016-04-18) now not only parse CHECK constraint but also enforces it.

MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can can set regular expression within check constraints in MySQL.
Eg.,:

```html
create table fk 
  ( 
    empid int not null unique, 
    age int check(age between 18 and 60), 
    email varchar(20) default 'N/A', 
    secondary_email varchar(20) check(secondary_email RLIKE'^[a-zA-Z]@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-z,A-Z]{2,4}'), 
    deptid int check(deptid in(10,20,30)) 
  ) 
;
```

This INSERT query will work:
insert into fk values(1,19,'a@a.com','a@b.com', 30);

This INSERT query will not work:
insert into fk values(2,19,'a@a.com','a@bc.com', 30);