# how to validate a string using mysql when inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a data called registration number like follows

```
COL/A-000001,
KAL/B-000023,
BAL/A-000452,
```

I know how to validate this type of format using php.But i want to do it when i create the table.IS it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean with "when I create the table" ?

Comment: We assumed if this column type is `VARCHAR(12)` i want to validate it with `4 strings` ,`2 symbols` with `6 integers`

Comment: @BartFriederichs So does it possible when create table ?

Comment: If you want to do validation on the database you'll have to use sql triggers.

Here is an example:
http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

change (example_tbl / field_name) to your (table / field) names respectively.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert
     BEFORE INSERT ON example_tbl FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.field_name NOT_REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}\/[A-Z]-\d{6}$' THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: regex failed';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```