# My regex in my MySQL database isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, regex, triggers, xampp

My regex check in my MySQL server doesn't seem to be working or I'm making a really obvious mistake (sorry if it is I just can't spot it if so).

[image: Regular expression]

Trigger: trig_check_memebers

Event:   INSERT

Table:   tbl_members

Statement:
BEGIN
IF (NEW.member_email REGEXP '^(\w+@\w+.\w+)$') = FALSE THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'invalid email';
END IF;
END

Timing:  BEFORE

Created: NULL

sql_mode:NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

So that is my trigger just to show the regex I have, it is highlighted. And this is my proof (may be wrong) that it works for the data I want to input.

[image: Regex tester]

I know its a bad regex I just started learning it and wanted to test basic stuff, like I know that if there is a email like xxx.yyy@foo.bar it wont have the same result.

And here is my test data producing an error.

[image: Test data]

```
INSERT INTO tbl_members VALUES ('jeff', 'password', 'hardy', 'jeff', 'matt',     'you@you.you');
```

[image: Test data]

```
Error
  SQL query:


  INSERT INTO tbl_members VALUES ('jeff', 'password', 'hardy', 'jeff', 'matt',     'you@you.you')
  MySQL said: Documentation

  #1644 - invalid email
```

^ not really code, error message.

```
<?php
    //Variables
    $database_name;
    $dbc;
    $table_create_queries;
    $triggers;
    //Initialization
    $database_name = 'PolySoft';
    $dbc = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', null);

    $table_create_queries = array
    (
        //Members Table
        'tbl_members' => 'CREATE TABLE tbl_members(member_username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        member_password varchar(60) NOT NULL,
        member_surname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        member_forename varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        member_othernames varchar(40),
        member_email varchar(254),
        UNIQUE(member_email),
        PRIMARY KEY(member_username));'
        ,
        //Addresses Table
        'tbl_addresses' => 'CREATE TABLE tbl_addresses(address_postcode varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        address_country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        address_county varchar(255),
        address_city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        address_town varchar(255),
        address_street varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        address_house_name_or_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(address_postcode));'
    );
    $triggers = array
    (
        'check_members' =>'CREATE TRIGGER trig_check_memebers 
            BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_members 
            FOR EACH ROW 
            BEGIN
                IF (NEW.member_email REGEXP \'^(\\\\w+@\\\\w+\\\\.\\\\w+)$\') = FALSE THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE \'12345\'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = \'invalid email\';
                END IF;
            END;'
    );

    $dbc->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $database_name");
    $dbc->query("CREATE DATABASE $database_name");
    $dbc->close();
    $dbc = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', null, $database_name);
    foreach($table_create_queries as $tbl => $query)
    {
        $dbc->query($query);
    }
    foreach($triggers as $trig => $query)
    {
        $dbc->query($query);
    }
    $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_members VALUES ('jeff', 'password', 'hardy', 'jeff', 'matt', 'you@you.you')");
    //$dbc->query();
    $dbc->close();
    ?>
```

If anyone is wondering why I'm dropping and creating the database: the code would never be actually on a server, its so that for my assignment I can just run the script on any server so I don't have to rely on bringing in my PC to show how it works. The tutor can just run this on his to create it and it is also for my database module too so having all the sql in one location is also good for my reference etc.

[Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)

The top answer is what got me the trigger code.

Comment: I've fixed up your images. Now I've done so, if you could swap the first, third and fourth for their text equivalents, that would be great! The image of the regex tester is quite useful, but all the others would be good to copy and paste from, and that's not possible with images (you'll find this a common response to using images - people will ask you for text versions - of code, error messages, etc).

Comment: (Other than that feedback, it's a good question. I should think you'll get an answer quickly with that level of detail.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
^[A-Za-z_]+@[A-Za-z_]+\\.[A-Za-z_]+$
```

Comment: IF (NEW.member_email REGEXP '^[:word:]+@[:word:]+\.[:word:]+$') = FALSE THEN

Is that what the final regex should look like, it didn't work either.

Comment: Do I need the extra '\' or is that escaping the '\' like I assumed?

Comment: @Fat_Llama I don't trust in the `\w` in mysql, not sure if its engine supports that. That's why I put the 2nd option.

Comment: @Fat_Llama btw, try changin `[:word:]` but `[[:alnum:]]`

Comment: @Fat_Llama I've put the plain mysql regex, but you have to change `\\.` to `\\\\.` for php code

Comment: yeah I've done the \\\\. in php will try the second option now.

Comment: That's great, the second option did it. Do you know why the second did but not the first?

Comment: also so I know for future ref. do you edit your question to take the first solution off in case it confuses anyone else?

Comment: `[:word:]` is a character set, identical to `[dorw:]`, it is not a word test.