# Restrict content on mysql table column, no commas or semicolon

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know how to add a constraint to a column "ce_email" that I don't want to have commas or semicolons? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: MySQL accepts the syntax for `check constraint`, but it doesn't actually do anything.  So, if you want to do this you need to use a trigger.

Comment: You could add a regex trigger.

Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression