# sql regex check constraint

Tags: mysql

in mysql i trying to verify a valid email but i don't
know how to use a regex with constraint
 i don't want use TRIGGER it is possible??!

Comment: MySQL does not support `CHECK` constraint so IMHO it seems not possible to do it without trigger.

Comment: Are you trying to do that in MySQL or PHP?

Comment: You are trying to verify when selecting or inserting/updating? You could verify server side for the inserting/updating. You could select with a regex in where clause.

Comment: From version 8, MySQL does support `check`constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

In mySql you could use this  for valid email or NOT REGEX for find the invalid

```
select email from your_table where email  
        REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

or for ORACLE

```
SELECT email 
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (email, '[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}');
```

but remember is not an absolute solution for this you could find useful this SO post [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: no i don't went to select from database i wen't add a constraint  when i went to insert vales in my table

Comment: For this you should create trigger, ( see how create trigger) and apply the regexp in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression

Comment: thanks for your help,i'm beginner and i look for   a simple method

Comment: If you want to add constraints to the database solution it is the trigger I do not think there are easier solutions. If you want to use simple solutions to write because you start checking on the values before inserting them in the db