# State Abbreviation check constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a check constraint for state abbreviations. I only want to allow a two character insert for the State column. What would be the code? 
my code was:
State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_StateAbbr CHECK (State like 'xx')

I am assuming putting the xx in there will only allow xx for the state.
Would I put CHECK (State like '[A-Z][A-Z]')?

Comment: Only on MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: Your regex will work (assuming Mysql 8.0+ otherwise you'll need to use a trigger [like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)). You could also use `CHECK(State like '[A-Z]{2}')` or `CHECK(State like '[a-zA-Z]{2}')` if you want to allow lower case.

Comment: Why not have a table with state codes and just use a foreign key to that table?

Answer (score 1):

With most versions of MySQL, it makes no difference.  A `check` constraint is accepted as syntax, but it is not implemented.

That leaves you with several choices.  First, ignore the issue.  This would be the most common approach.  Second, use a trigger.  That makes for messy code and is not optimal.

The third approach is to create a table with all valid state abbreviations.  Then you can use a *foreign key* constraint, to ensure that the value is valid.