# How to check in MySQL if a string is solely made up of the letters of the English alphabet?

Tags: mysql, create-table

Consider the following minimal example.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Student (
  Name varchar(50),
  CHECK (isEnglish(Name))
)
```

I want to add a constraint that the name is in the English alphabet (a-z, A-Z) while inserting a new tuple in the `STUDENT` table. How do I do this? That is, what should I put in place of `isEnglish(Name)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps but only works on MySQL 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  Name varchar(50) CHECK (Name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]+$')
)
```