# Pattern constraint in mySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to create a table for `student` with the attributes `enroll_id` and `std_name`.
The `enroll_id` is Primary Key of the table and the format of `enroll_id` is `year`+`brach` code (CS,EC,MC,CV)+college code (001 to 300)+ entry type(D for lateral entry or 0 for not) + 3 digit number example 2021CS213D011 , 2021CV2010011.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  enroll_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  std_name VARCHAR(24),
  CONSTRAINT valid_enroll_id CHECK (enroll_id ~ '^\d{4}(CS|EC|MC|CV)\d{3}(D|0)\d{5}$')
);
```

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question

Comment: The `~` is postgres syntax... or as far as I know. What mysql version are you using?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a PostgreSQL script into MySQL? The [Regular Expressions docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) show that to check for a match you use the `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` operators, not `~`

Comment: In fact, there are duplicate questions like this, much clearer one: [Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL, try the following to define your table -

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  enroll_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  std_name VARCHAR(24),
  CONSTRAINT valid_enroll_id CHECK (enroll_id REGEXP '^20[0-9]{2}(CS|EC|MC|CV)[0-9]{3}(D|0)[0-9]{3}$')
);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/1rF1v2fa)

For Postgres, use the following to define your table -

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  enroll_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  std_name VARCHAR(24),
  CONSTRAINT valid_enroll_id CHECK (enroll_id ~ '^20\d{2}(CS|EC|MC|CV)\d{3}(D|0)\d{3}$')
);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ku2T7N7n)